Applying a filter before joining tables
How can I filter joining table results ?
I have 3 tables:
User:
 id: str
 full_name: str
 is_active: bool # NEED TO FILTER BY THIS
 tags: Mapped[list["Tag"]] = relationship(
        "Tag", secondary=user_tag, back_populates="users"
    )

Tag:
 id: str
 name: str
 users: Mapped[list["Tag"]] = relationship(
        "User", secondary=user_tag, back_populates="tags", lazy="selectin"
    )

user_tag = Table(
    "user_tag",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
    Column("tag_id", ForeignKey("tag.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
)

I'm getting all tags like this:
all_tags= await session.scalars(select(Tag))
If I want to get all users for this tag, I do like this:
all_tags_with_users = await session.scalars(select(Tag).join(Tag.users)
But how can I join only active users ? Where I should put where condition ? I assume it should be like this:
all_tags_with_only_active_users = await session.scalars(select(Tag).join(Tag.users, onclause=Tag.users.contains(User.id) & Tag.users.is_active=True)


Use PropComparator.and_ to add an on clause.
select(Tag).join(
  Tag.users.and_(Users.is_active == True)
)

See Combining Relationship with Custom ON Criteria in the SQLAlchemy docs for more.
